Maximal irregular polygon inside a regular polygon
Problem:
We have a regular $n$-gon. We want to choose some of it's vertices ($A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_m$), so  these vertices form a completely irregular $m$-gon. Meaning that all of it's sides have different length. Given $n$ what is the maximum of $m$?
My first attempt:
In a regular $n$-gon there are $n/2$ or $(n-1)/2$ different lengths between the vertices (depending on if $n$ is even or odd). So obviously $m \leq n/2$ or $(n-1)/2$.
Number the $n$-gon's vertices from $1$ to $n$. If we want all the sides to have a different length, then there can't be two connected vertices with the same difference of their number. (I.e.: $1,2,4$ is an irregular triangle but $1,2,3$ is not).
So for any $m$ that exists the indexes can be the following: $1; \, 1+1; \, 1+1+2; \, \ldots; \, 1 + 1 + \ldots + (m-1)$. This last one can be written as $1 + (m)(m-1)/2$. The side connecting the last and first vertices has to be different as well, therefore $1-(1+(m)(m-1)/2) \geq m \,(\operatorname{mod} n)$.
This is the point where i'm kind of lost and not sure how to continue (or is it worth continuig at all?)
My second attempt:
In a completely irregular polygon every side and every diagonal has different lenghts (this needs a proof i know) Therefore there are $\binom{m}{2}$ different lengths. So the maximum of $\binom{m}{2}$ is $n/2$ if $n$ even $(n-1)/2$ if $n$ odd. From this $m^2 -m \leq n$ (even), or $m^2 - m +1 \leq n$ (odd).
Question: Is my second attempt correct? If not how can you reach the correct answer? Is there a flaw in my first attempt or is just unfinished? Any help is appreciated.

Let $V_1, \cdots, V_n$ denote the vertices of the regular $n$-gon (moving in the anticlockwise direction). Suppose that we connect two vertices $V_a$ and $V_b$ with a line $L_{V_a,V_b}$ and another two vertices $V_c$ and $V_d$ with a line $L_{V_c,V_d}$. Then $|L_{V_a,V_b}| = |L_{V_c,V_d}| \iff b-a \: (\text{mod}\: n) = d-c \: (\text{mod}\: n)$ whenever $b-a \: (\text{mod}\: n)$ and $d-c \: (\text{mod}\: n)$ are both less than or equal to $\frac{n}{2}$. However, in a polygon, this anomaly can only occur once.
Suppose we create the completely irregular polygon from the vertices $V_{i_1}, \cdots, V_{i_m}$ with $i_1 = 1$ and $i_k<i_{k+1} \: \forall k\in\mathbb{N}$
Assume WLOG that the gap between each $i_k$ and $i_{k+1}$ is strictly increasing.
It becomes clear from the diagram below that if $n$ is a triangle number then the problem is trivial by setting the $i_1 = 1, i_2 = 2, i_3 = 4, i_4 = 7, \cdots  $

Hence we can set a lower bound on $m$ to be $\left\lfloor\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+8n}}{2}\right\rfloor$. This comes from reversing the formula for the largest $m^{th}$ triangle number smaller than $n$. Use the quadratic formula to solve $\frac{m(m+1)}{2} = n$ for $m$.
For example, if $21\leq n < 28$, define $i_1 = 1, i_2 = 2, i_3 = 4, i_4 = 7, i_5 = 11, i_6 = 16$
More specifically, let $m$ be such that $T_m \leq n < T_{m+1}$ where $T_m$ is the $m^{th}$ triangle number, definie $i_1 = 1$ and $i_k = T_{k-1}+1 \: \forall \: 2 \leq k \leq m$.
Below is an example with $n=20$ where $m=5$

I will not show rigorously that this is an upper bound as it follows fairly naturally from the pigeonhole principle. To be more specific, every $i_{k+1}-i_k$ (The 'distance' between the vertices) must be different and $1- i_m \: (\text{mod}\: n)$ must be different to all those differences. This means that the $m^{th}$ triangle number cannot be larger than $n$.
Hence the maximum size of $m$ is:
\begin{equation}
m=\left\lfloor\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+8n}}{2}\right\rfloor
\end{equation}
